# AWS Ubuntu 14 - Can't SSH After Reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Had an issue where an instance became unresponsive and was forced into a reboot.  After the reboot I could ping the server but could not SSH into the server.

Ultimately I created a new instance and connected the volume to the new instance.  However I would like to make sure when I reboot this instance I don't run into the same problem.

Looking at the console log I see:

[    2.968537] EXT4-fs (xvda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem

[    2.972324] EXT4-fs (xvda1): write access will be enabled during recovery

[    3.095607] EXT4-fs (xvda1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs

[    3.354696] EXT4-fs (xvda1): 40 orphan inodes deleted

[    3.358010] EXT4-fs (xvda1): recovery complete

[    3.465864] EXT4-fs (xvda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

My sshd_config file has two changes from the default UsePAM was set to no and PasswordAuthentication was set to yes.  I don't think that had anything to do with it.

My /etc/fstab file was set to:
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
/dev/xvdb   /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
/dev/xvdg /hd3 auto noatime 0 0

## /dev/xvdf /hd3 auto noatime 0 0

/dev/xvdf /hd2 auto noatime 0 0
/dev/xvdh /hd4 auto noatime 0 0
/dev/xvdh /hd4 auto noatime 0 0
/dev/xvdi /vol auto noatime 0 0
/dev/xvdi /hd5 auto noatime 0 0

I checked all the obvious things like making sure I'm connecting to the right IP, etc.

Any idea on why this did not allow SSH?

Comment: if the filesystem was corrupted and opened in read-only mode, then it couldn't create or write to any tmp or log files when you tried to ssh.

Comment: Did you check your security settings on the new instance to make sure TCP/22 was allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> My sshd_config file has two changes from the default UsePAM was set to no and PasswordAuthentication was set to yes. I don't think that had anything to do with it.

Actually that almost certainly *is* your problem. On a Linux system with PAM, attempting to login bypassing PAM is not guaranteed to work, and generally does not.

Set `UsePAM yes` and try again.